# How to edit my mySQL query to select the users with this requirement?

Tags: php, mysql

I have the table below, and I want to select all the users that have a row with type_id equals to 3 and a row with type_id equals to 5.

I know I am wrong, but how shall I edit my query?

The table

```
user --- type--- type_id
abc ---- form --- 3
abc ---- form --- 5
abc ---- form --- 6
```

The query

```
Select user from table where type = 'form' and type_id = 3 and type_id = 5
```

Comment: You mean type_id of 3 **_or_** 5, surely?

Comment: @JonStirling he needs to  have both 3 and 5...

Comment: Exactly, so OR. I.e. you want the rows where type id is either, 3 _or_ 5. They can't be both at the same time.

Comment: I think he may mean that the user abc must have a record with type_id = 3 AND must also have a record with type_id = 5.

Comment: @devlincarnate exactly that

Comment: Ugh, if that's the case the schema needs fixing...

Comment: @jonstirling it looks normalised to me

Comment: @Strawberry Yeah, okay, that's fair. Not how I would have done it, but that's beside the point (and also, reading the question again,  I  think I made too many assumptions about the table...).

Answer (score 1):

You can join on the same table and check if `type_id` have the values you want:

```
select t1.user 
from table t1
inner join on t1.user = t2.user and t2.type='form' and t2.type_id = 5
where t1.type = 'form' 
and t1.type_id = 3
```

Comment: That looks better than mine.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Thanks again.

Comment: This becomes cumbersome if you want to search for more values - so 3, 5, and 6, say.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select user 
  from table 
 where type = 'form' 
   and type_id IN(3, 5)
 Group
    By user
Having count(1) = 2;
```

Comment: Looks great! Could you please describe the `1` in `Having count(1)`? Thank you.

Comment: Well, you've got to count something. You can use 'sheep' if you prefer.

Comment: What is a sheep?